# Is Subsonic 3.0 safe for production use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subsonic, subsonic3, production

I'm interested in using Subsonic 3.0 for developing a new ASP.Net MVC application that will be going into production use soon. Would this be a feasible option? Does anyone have an idea when 3.0 is going to be released? Is anyone else using it on a production MVC application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm getting there - we're in the clean up phase and I'm happy to say Eric's jumped back into the fray :). I ran perf tests the other day and fixed up some bottle-necks and the core is pretty much where we want it to be.

I have no idea when it will be ready...

Comment: Thanks Rob, I've decided to just start using it and see how far I get. I'm hacking on the source as well, if I accidentally fix something I'll send in a patch :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using it on a production site yet, although I am building a future production site with it, but its a hobby project so I can't get fired if the DAL has a bug and SS4 will probably be out before my hobby project.

So far I have not run across any show stoppers or actually any bugs at all and in the past I've found that if you do find an issue Rob is pretty good about getting a patch in pretty quick.  So I guess to answer your question it's probably not "production ready", but in playing around with it I felt it was pretty darn solid and chose it over LINQtoSQL or Entity Framework.  I'd recommend isolating your DAL (IRepository) that way if you run into something with SS you can swap out with something else fairly quickly.

Regarding as to when it is ready - I'll let Rob chime in on that one.  I think he is using it for building out some other app so he's sort of using that to dog-fooding SS3 - my guess is it will be a couple months yet though.

Answer (score 0):

I think for me the only show stopper is the fact that it doesn't run in medium trust.

While for nearly all projects we work on this isnt an issue as its a dedicated environment for fast "get-em up" sites that subsonic is REALLY good for this sucks as it means that a shared host is not possible... :(

but subsonic 2.0 is great for that even if its lacking linq support.

p.s i know they are working on this :)